# How is the "Total city size" requirement calculated?

Tags: simcity-4

In SimCity 4, some rewards require a "total city size of [*xyz*]".

How is this number calculated? Is it based on a single city "tile", or the entire region?

Comment: population basically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It refers to the total population of the city (not region).

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: This is correct; "city size" refers only to the current city. There are a few rewards (Resort Hotel and Tourist Trap) that instead list regional population requirements.

Comment: Source is from personal experience from playing the game.